# Sign PGP key to which I added identity once again (i.e. also sign new identities)

Tags: gnupg, pgp, enigmail

I am using the Key Management dialog of Enigmail (in Thunderbird) to manage my keys, as it's more convenient than command line, but also more stable than the GnuPG alternative (Kleopatra).

So now I ran into a problem in that I added two more identities to the key, but I cannot get it signed again with another key, because allegedly the key is already signed with that key. This is of course true, but the newly added identities are **not** signed, yet.

How can I "renew" a signature (be it from another key of mine or other people trusting me/my key) so that all identities on the key are signed in the end?

Note: the solution can be command line as well, that's fine. But at the moment I'm at loss as to how to proceed.

---

Using GPG version 2.0.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some fiddling, I managed to do it on the command line. It was relatively trivial once I figured out how to tell `gpg2` which key to use to sign the other key.

```
gpg2 -u <key-ID> --sign-key <user@domain>
```

where `<key-ID>` is the ID of the key *with which* to sign and `<user@domain>` is one user identity or the key ID of the key *to sign*. I.e. basically: `gpg2 -u SIGNER --sign-key SIGNEE` ...

This is a limitation of the Enigmail user interface, so command line seems to be a reasonable workaround.